# Proper way to switch between parent component and child component on button click

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React. I am trying to create a CRUD Data Table. I have a data table in my parent component. And reusable Popup component and data input form component which have all inputs to add data to table. Currently input form shows inside the Popup. In some scenarios I need to show the input from in the same window instead of showing popup. Basically hide the data table and show the input form.

Here is my current code:

Parent Component - Table (I have simplified the code)

```
import CommonTableForm from "./CommonTableForm"
import Popup from '../PopupComponent';

const [openPopup, setOpenPopup] = useState(false)
const [isUsingPopup, setIsUsingPopup] = useState({false})

render (
    //Add New Button and Data Table
    <Button onClick={() => setOpenPopup(true)}>Add New</Button>
    < TableContainer >
         <TableHeader />
           <TableBody>
           <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Full Name</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Email</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
         </TableBody>
     </ >

    //Popup Component here
    <Popup
        title="Add Data"
        openPopup={openPopup}
        setOpenPopup={setOpenPopup}
    >
        //Input field form Component
        <CommonTableForm 
          someDataPassHere={data}/>
    </Popup>
)
```

*CommonTableForm* Component have a form and inputs

*Popup* Component have the Popup Modal code

When *isUsingPopup=false*, CommonTableForm Component should be shown in same page. But initially it has to be hidden. On Add New button clicks table has to hide and CommonTableForm Component should show.

**When I click the Add New Button, What is the best way to disable the Popup and hide the data table itself and then show the CommonTableForm Component?
Can I use *React Router* for this?**[image: For more understanding]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common pattern I have see in such scenarios is conditional rendering:

```
render(){
if (check of showing on same View){
        return(
    //Input field form Component
    <CommonTableForm 
      someDataPassHere={data}/>
      )
}
if (check for showing on pop up){
        return(
        <>
        <Popup
            title="Add Data"
            openPopup={openPopup}
            setOpenPopup={setOpenPopup}
        >
            //Input field form Component
            <CommonTableForm 
            someDataPassHere={data}/>
        </Popup>
        </>
      )
}
```

You can add ternary operator and return null initially and the component you want to click of button:

```
   <div className="row">
      { //Check if button clicked
        (this.state.clicked)
          ? <CommonTableForm someDataPassHere={data}/>
          : null 
      }
    </div>
```

Comment: Initially CommonTableForm Component has to be hidden. How can I hide the table and show the CommonTableForm Component on Button click? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: See if it helps, I have added one more snippet, it can help you solve your problem